# Is it possible to increase the size of VirtualBox that's set up as "Fixed drives"?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

i formatted as "Fixed drives" rather than dynamic and feel like allocated size is too small...

Comment: Yes that is possible in various ways, see for example discussion https://serverfault.com/questions/779106/how-to-decrease-virtual-size-capacity-of-a-virtualbox-vdi-file/779109

Comment: thanks! will definitely check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first clone you current drive

by using following command:

> VboxManage clonehd

in my computer it looked exactly like this:

> VBoxManage clonehd /Users/gubatron/VirtualBox VMs/windows7-64bit

then to resize the disk by using following command:

> VBoxManage modifyhd –resize

for me it looked like this:

> VBoxManage modifyhd /Users/gubatron/VirtualBox
>   VMs/windows7-64bit/windows7-64bit.vdi –resize 40960

then mount it

Have a nice day

Comment: Please rate my post :)